# Can we find the skewness of Fourier coefficients?

Tags: signal-analysis

Can I find skewness of the Fourier coefficients (the coefficients obtained after taking FFT of a 1D signal)?

Answer (score 2):

Skewness is, classicaly,  a measure of **asymmetry for a probability distribution of a real-valued random variable** about its mean. You can check previous discussions at [What do Skewness and Kurtosis represent?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30435/what-do-skewness-and-kurtosis-represent) or  [Measuring Skewness: A Forgotten Statistic?](http://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v19n2/doane.pdf) Your question can be interpreted in many ways, here are the three most obvious to me:

- If you talk about complex Fourier coefficients, the "real-valued" assumption does not hold, and unless one uses some [exotic probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_probability) theory, I cannot give it any sense,
- If you talk about deterministic absolute Fourier coefficients, the skewness should be zero, due to the Hermitian symmetry fro real signals,
- Last, you can consider a stochastic  $X$ the positive half of the magnitude  power spectrum as a probability distribution (provided you normalize it to unit-sum), compute the mean (not zero anymore), the standard deviation and finally the skewness coefficient with $$E\left(\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^3\right)$$
  and either the exact (if you know the analytic formulae for $X$) or its empirical form.

Comment: I am up with the last point; I have taken half of the spectrum and taken only the real part; and applied the skewness. I am getting non-zero values and the result is fine. It is actually making my work done. But I am unsure about the distribution of the Fourier coefficients. I mean we calculate skewness for a guassian distribution and see the deviation; Is it the case here with the Fourier coefficients? Kindly reply.